# Is there a generalisation of the Vivanti-Pringsheim theorem for several variables?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

The [Vivanti-Pringsheim theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivanti%E2%80%93Pringsheim_theorem) states that if $f(z)$ has a power series with non-negative coefficients and a radius of convergence $R > 0$, then it has a singularity at $R$. So to find the radius of convergence of $f$, one only needs to evaluate it along the real axis.

Can this theorem be generalised to several complex variables? If $f(z_1, \dots, z_n)$ has a non-negative power series and a finite radius of convergence, can then the dominating singularity be found on a point with all coordinates being real numbers? Or is there at least some restriction on the places where it can be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed, a multi-dimensional version of Pringsheim Theorem holds true.

If a power series $\sum_\alpha c_\alpha z^\alpha$ has real, nonnegative coefficients
$c_\alpha$, then the series is singular at every boundary point
$(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ of the
domain of convergence at which all the coordinates $r_j$ are positive real numbers.

A proof (essentially similar to the one variable case) is given p.10 of the very nice Lecture notes on several complex
variables by Harold P. Boas, available [here](https://haroldpboas.gitlab.io/courses/650-2011c/notes.pdf).